# iterator function does not iterate over all elements

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, jupyter

I have two functions:

```py
# function to get number of wanted atom
def atom_number_grabber(sum_formula, wanted_atom):
    match = re.match(r"([A-Z][a-z]*)([0-9]*)", sum_formula, re.I)
    if match:
        items = match.groups()
    if items[0] == wanted_atom:
        atom_number = items[1]
        if not atom_number:
            atom_number = "1"
        return atom_number
    else:
        pass
```

and

```py
#function to iterate over all elements
def iterator(sum_formula_list, atom_number_grabber, wanted_atom):
    for sum_formula in sum_formula_list:
        return atom_number_grabber(sum_formula, wanted_atom)
```

However, when I use my iterator function, it does not iterate over all of the elements in my list

```py
test_list = ["C25", "H32", "O8"]

iterator(sum_formula_list = test_list, atom_number_grabber = atom_number_grabber, wanted_atom = "O")
```

output:

desired output:

```py
8
```

To my suprise the function only iterates over the first element; so if I change my wanted_atom to "C", the code works properly:

```py
iterator(sum_formula_list = test_list, atom_number_grabber = atom_number_grabber, wanted_atom = "C")
```

output

```py
25
```

Comment: An unconditional `return` in a `for` loop will end that loop on its first iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an unconditional `return` in a `for` loop, that loop will only iterate once, and then exit.

Given that your function is called `iterator`, maybe you want to return ... an iterator. In that case you could use `yield` instead of `return`. Make it conditional so that you only yield when you have a result. Like so:

```
def iterator(sum_formula_list, atom_number_grabber, wanted_atom):
    for sum_formula in sum_formula_list:
        result = atom_number_grabber(sum_formula, wanted_atom)
        if result:
            yield result
```

Now the main program can consume that iterator, for instance with `*`:

```
print(*iterator(sum_formula_list = test_list, atom_number_grabber = atom_number_grabber, wanted_atom = "O"))
```

Output: `8`

### Other comments

- There is an indentation that is wrong in your first function: the second `if` might be executed when `items` is not defined. This second `if` block should be inside the block of the first `if` block.
- `else: pass` is useless.
- As you use the `re.I` flag, there is no use in mixing upper and lower case with `[A-Z][a-z]*`. Just do `[A-Z]+` then.
- You can access groups through indexing on the `match` object. There is no need to retrieve the `groups`. Just be aware that `match[0]` is the whole match, and `match[1]` is the first group.
- `if not atom_number` can be done with a logical `or` operator, like `return match[2] or "1"`
- There is no need to pass `atom_number_grabber` as argument -- it can be used directly.
- It seems more practical to have the first function *only* take care of extracting the parts, while the second function would do the filtering on the wanted atom.
- The second function can use comprehension syntax.

Here is how it could be done:

```
import re 

# function to split string into atom name and number
def atom_parts(sum_formula):
    match = re.match(r"([A-Z]*)([0-9]*)", sum_formula, re.I)
    return match[1], int("0" + match[2]) or 1

# function to iterate over all elements
def iterator(sum_formula_list, wanted_atom):
    return (number for name, number in map(atom_parts, sum_formula_list) 
                   if name == wanted_atom)

test_list = ["C25", "H32", "O8"]

print(*iterator(sum_formula_list = test_list, wanted_atom = "O"))  # 8
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments and your time!